# Magento Register Form validate with VarienForm function get response

Tags: ajax, magento

Currently I am creating a register form and validating it using Magento VarienForm method. I just want to know how I can get response whether the user has passed the validation or not? If it fails then I will stop the ajax. Here is my code:

```
var dataForm = new VarienForm('register-form', true);
jQuery('#register-form').submit(function(e){
    jQuery.post( "<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>quickcheckout/index/register", jQuery( "#register_form_mobile" ).serialize()).done(function( data ) {
    var successRegister = isNumber(data);
        if(successRegister)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/03/custom-from-validation-in-magento.html

```
 var theForm = new VarienForm('frm_feedback', true);
```

Where `frm_feedback` is your **form id**

```
   if (theForm.validator && theForm.validator.validate())   
   {
     // if validation successful pass then
   }
  else
  {
  //magento validation fire
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have found out the answer, hope it will help others:

```
var dataForm = new VarienForm('register-form', true);

if (!dataForm.validator.validate())
{
   //fail pass validation
}
else
{
  //success pass validation
}
```